# Entity Framework 6 asp.net Code First Setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hi guys I am spinning wheels on this one. I am using EF6 and ASP.Net 4.6. I have a given table which has student information and parent information. A student can have many parents and a parent can have many students. Call this table 'Contact'. I am to create a table called 'Request' which will hold information for a parent submitting a request for his student. I will create a lookup table with two columns, one for student id and one for parent id called 'StudentParents'. I want to be able to have the parent log in, select his student from a drop down of all of his students and submit the request. The many to many relationship is throwing me off as far as my include statements. How can I get EF to set up this structure so that when I GetRequest(id) I can get the Student info and the Parent info to be included? Here is my code that wont Include anything other than the request.

```
    public class Contact
{
   [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string student_id { get; set; }//This is the Student ID
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string middle_initial { get; set; }
    public string grade { get; set; }
    public int current_school_id { get; set; }
    public string current_school_name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parent Last Name")]
    public string contact_first_name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parent Middle Name")]
    public string contact_middle_name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parent Last Name")]
    public string contact_last_name { get; set; }
    public string contact_relationship { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parent Email")]
    public string contact_email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parent Address")]
    public string login { get; set; }//This is the Parent ID
    public string Classif_description { get; set; }
}

 public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Student student_id { get; set; }
    public Contact login { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First School Choice")]
    public string firstSchool { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Second School Choice")]
    public string secSchool { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Rising Grade")]
    public string rising_grade { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReqSubmitted { get; set; }
    public string ReqStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public string ModifBy { get; set; }
}
    public class Parent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string contact_first_name { get; set; }
    public string contact_middle_name { get; set; }
    public string contact_last_name { get; set; }
    public string contact_relationship { get; set; }
    public string contact_email { get; set; }
    public string contact_address { get; set; }
    public string contact_city { get; set; }
    public string contact_zip { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string login { get; set; }
    public string contact_pw { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string phone_type { get; set; }

    public Parent() { }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }


}
   public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int student_id { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string middle_initial { get; set; }
    public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string grade { get; set; }
    public string Fed_race_description { get; set; }
    public string Classif_description { get; set; }
    public int current_school_id { get; set; }
    public string current_school_name { get; set; }
    public int home_school_id { get; set; }
    public string home_school_name { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        this.Parents = new HashSet<Parent>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}

 public class OEContext : DbContext
{
    public OEContext() : base("name=OEContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Students)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("login");
                x.MapRightKey("student_id");
                x.ToTable("StudentParents");
            }
            );
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have quite a bit of duplication here between these classes.  I don't think you even want a `Contact` class at all, rather your `Request` should have a both a `Parent` property and a `Student` property.

Comment: See this page for how to set up many<->many relationships in EF6, with or without navigation properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620

Comment: Yes. I am leaning towards having a `Request` which has a student.The `Student` class should have a list of parents. The question remains how to setup EF6 for the following type of structure. The `Contact` class is a model of the given table that has the student and the parent info. This is why I asked about the many to many. There are records in the Contact table that have multiple entries for the same student because he can have multiple parents (a mother and a father).

Comment: The `Contact` class is a model of the given table that has the student and the parent info. I haven't figured out how to pull the info from the Contact table. I am going to populate the `Student` table, the `Parent` table and the `StudentParents` table from the record that I pull back from Contact after the parent logs in and chooses the student for the request.  The question remains how to setup EF6 for the following type of structure. A Request has a Contact. I want to pull the Student and his Parent from each record in the Contact table.

Comment: Changed `Request` class and added this`        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Changed the strategy. Made Request have many Contacts. So I added a constructor to the request:

```
public Request()
{
    Contacts = new List<Contact>();
}
public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

Next I changed the contact class:

```
public int ContactId { get; set; }

public Contact() { }
public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
```

With this relationship I can pull both Parents and a student from the Contacts associated with the Request.